# pandas rolling_apply cumprod

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a rolling cumulative product to a series in pandas. My input series is:

```
   s
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
```

I would like to get a resulting series that gives me the cumulative product of the previous 'n' values. So if 'n' were 3, I would like to get:

```
   s
0  n/a
1  n/a
2  6
3  24
4  60
5  120
```

The code I have come up with uses rolling_apply and a lambda function and produces a TypeError:

```
import pandas as pnd
df = pnd.DataFrame()
df['s'] = [1,2,3,4]
print (df)
print (pnd.rolling_apply(df.s,2,lambda x : x.cumprod()))

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This is just a rolling regular product, isn't it?

Comment: I think you want `numpy.prod` instead of `cumprod`.

Comment: user2357112... I could be wrong, but I don't this pandas has a rolling_prod function

Comment: user2357112... np.prod(df.s,3) yields a scalar 720 (which is the product of all numbers in the series). This is not what I am looking for

Comment: `rolling_apply` the `prod`.

Comment: Thanks...that work! I will answer my own question for completeness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to user2357112. This is the code that I came up that works...

```
import pandas as pnd
df = pnd.DataFrame()
df['s'] = [1,2,3,4, 5, 6]
print (df)
print (pnd.rolling_apply(df.s,3,lambda x : x.prod()))
```