# Rolling cumulative function in python

Tags: python, pandas

All, I found a solution for rolling cumulative product in Python here - 
[prior solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461494/pandas-rolling-apply-cumprod)

But when I try to implement this functionality, I get the following output -

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_apply'
```

I think pandas removed this functionality in more recent versions, does anyone have a more current solution for a rolling cumprod() for columns in a dataframe?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

All, thank you for your messages.  I tried this - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295434/how-to-calculate-rolling-cumulative-product-on-pandas-dataframe) - and got the same `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_apply'` issue as before.  An example of the dataframe and expected output is in the image below.  This would be the rolling cumprod of the last 2 rows of data in raw_data.

[image]

Comment: show an example of you r dataframe an your expected output. See DataFrame.rolling

Comment: Second Answer in this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295434/how-to-calculate-rolling-cumulative-product-on-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

All, figured it out, rolling_apply was deprecated.  This functionality worked -

```
df['output'] = df['input'].rolling(5).apply(lambda x: x.prod())
```

Thanks for your help!